# Move manual Wordpress website as godaddy Installatron Application

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress website on Godaddy Deluxe hosting, which was manually placed in a directory by my developer,

In godaddy we can install and manage wordpress website throught their inbuilt installatron

Can anyone help me how to migrate the website so as it will be visible in installatron i.e in my applications of godaddy so that i can manage it from their

Regards

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Installatron Applications Browser.
- Find WordPress there
- Click on **Import existing install** button.
  [image: Import Existing Install]
- Choose domain and path where script is installed (**make it sure**).
- Click on **Next** button.
- For database information, you will require database name, username
  and password options for your previous WordPress.
- **Submit** the information and you will see the software being imported
  after sometime.
- Click on **Complete** button and you will be able to see the imported
  installation

and you're good to go..
.